# Get-ADUser filter out specific OU, custom column

Tags: powershell, csv, ou

trying to get an Audit report of active users.  We have an OU that I do not want to report on.

Give me all the active (enabled) AD accounts.  EXCEPT in a specific OU.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter{enabled -eq $true} | Select-object Samaccountname,surname,givenname `
        | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation C:\scripts\ActiveUsers.csv
```

How can I filter out `OU=Service Accounts`?

I also need to have a custom column in Column A of the csv output.
Example:  The word "ACME" in column A in all rows.

Thanks much
Esther

Answer (score 11):

## Filter on parent containers

The OU is part of the object's `DistinguishedName` property.

Use `Where-Object` to filter out objects that reside inside a certain OU by removing the first part of the `DistinguishedName` and comparing the rest with the `DistinguishedName` of the OU:

```
$OUDN = "OU=Service Accounts,OU=Accounts,DC=domain,DC=tld"
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true} | Where-Object { $_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*,$OUDN" }
```

---

If you know the OU name, but not the full `DistinguishedName`, you can remove immediate child objects of the OU from the results by splitting the distinguished name into compartments and comparing the second one (the immediate parent container) to the name you want to exclude:

```
$OUName = "Service Accounts"
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true} | Where-Object {
    $ObjectCN,$ParentCN,$null = $_.DistinguishedName -split "(?<=[^\\]),"
    $ParentCN -ne "OU=$OUName"
}
```

or exclude any object with the given OU name in its ancestral path:

```
$OUName = "Service Accounts"
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true} | Where-Object {
    $ObjectCN,$ParentCNs = $_.DistinguishedName -split "(?<=[^\\]),"
    $ParentCNs -notcontains "OU=$OUName"
}
```

---

## Custom property values

`Select-Object` supports calculated properties. You can supply a calculated property with a static expression as the first property to select, like so:

```
Get-ADUser | Select-Object @{Name="MyCustomColumn";Expression={"ACME"}},Name
```

Exported to a CSV, the above example would have the colunm headers "MyCustomColumn" and "Name" in col A and B respectively, col A holding the value "ACME" always, whereas col B would hold the individual Names of the users

Comment: Where-Object has really bad performance. people suggest using LDAPFilter over Where-Object

Comment: @KolobCanyon Correct, but you can't do wildcard filtering against the `DistinguishedName` attribute using an LDAP filter :-)

Comment: I just learned that the hard way yesterday... So frustrating!

Comment: @KolobCanyon, how to incorporate the LDAPFilter instead of the Where-Object?

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer You don't, LDAP doesn't support partial name filtering on `distinguishedName`

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @MathiasR.Jessen.

Answer (score 6):

This worked - thanks gang.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {enabled -eq $true} | ? {$_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*,OU=Service Accounts,*"}
```

And the custom column:

```
Select-Object -Property @{n="ColumnA"; e={"ACME"}}
```